# I am trying to run gradlew command in android studio with flutter but i am getting an error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

command: ./gradlew signinReport

**//error i am getting:**

```
> Task :gradle:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\dev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
```

**//my sdk is: android api 34, extension level 7 platform jetbrains runtime version 17.0.6
//this is my project level gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        // id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can someone suggest what can i do to resolve the error??

I tried upgrading the gradle version to 8.0.2 and kotlin version to 1.8.0 but the error still remains.